# Display information from apex class into visualforce page (remote action)

Tags: apex, visualforce

In apex I have a method that return an wrapper object like this :

```
public class WrapperCalcul{
    public String nb;
    public String coutTot;
}

@RemoteAction
public static WrapperCalcul submitForm(String nb, String montant){
   WrapperCalcul wrapCalc = new WrapperCalcul();
    wrapCalc.nb = nb;
    wrapCalc.coutTot = montant;

    return wrapCalc;
}
```

I want to display the values of `wrapCalc` into a simple VF (one value in one field), how can I do that ?

Comment: is it important to use RemoteAction?

Comment: yes I call this method from JS (this is a one page form, that use JS to work). Is it annoying ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do something like,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sampleJSRemoteFunction() {
        var nb; //get nb value
        var coutTot; //get couTot value

        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.<Your-ControllerName>.submitForm}',
            nb, coutTot, 
            function(result, event){
                if (event.status) {
                    //handle the result. You can use js to populate these values in DOM.
                    console.log(result.nb);
                    console..log(result.coutTot);
                } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                    console.error(event.message+"-"+event.where);
                } else {
                    console.error(event.message);
                }
            }, 
            {escape: true}
        );
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

An Apex wrapper will be returned in the `result` object of the `callback` function stated within your Visualforce Remoting call. Refer the following link to understand what, the `event` and `result` object return - [Handling Visualforce Remoting Response](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_handling_response.htm).

The sample code to access the Apex Wrapper class values and display them in on the Visualforce page is as below.

**Visualforce Code**

```
<apex:page id="pgDisplay" controller="DisplayRemotingDataSample" standardStylesheets="false">

    <script type="text/javascript">

       function getRemoteValues() {

            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                '{!$RemoteAction.DisplayRemotingDataSample.submitForm}',
                'Sample nb', //nb, 
                'Sample montant', //montant, 
                function(result, event){

                    if(event.status){
                        console.log('Success: ' + result.nb);
                        document.getElementById('divNb').innerHTML = result.nb;
                        document.getElementById('divMontant').innerHTML = result.coutTot;
                    }
                    else if(event.type === 'exception'){
                        console.log('Callback failed ' + event.message);
                    }

                }
            );
        }

    </script>

    <!-- Clientside Controls with values returned through Visualforce Remoting -->
    <div id="divOutputClient">
        <div id="divNb"/>
        <div id="divMontant"/><br/>
    </div>

    <input id="btnGetValue" onclick="getRemoteValues()" type="button" value="Submit" />

</apex:page>
```

The above code passes 2 hard-coded string values to the Visualforce Remoting method as input params which are returned as a part of the Apex Wrapper. The `result` object returned within the `callback` is then used to display the values passed from the server within 2 `div` elements.